# Aggregate Count Data with Key Names

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Fisrt, I've aggregate the data into this form as presented below:

query:

```
{
 $group:{
     _id:{
     date:"$date"
    ,order_id: "$order_id"
    ,payment_name:"$payment_name" 
         }
        }

}
```

aggregated result :

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : "2018-06-07",
        "order_id" : "180607009399",
        "payment_name" : "creditcard"
    }
}


{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : "2018-06-06",
        "order_id" : "180606009394",
        "payment_name" : "ATM"
    }
}


{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : "2018-06-06",
        "order_id" : "180606009393",
        "payment_name" : "creditcard"
    }
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : "2018-06-07",
        "order_id" : "180606009395",
        "payment_name" : "ATM"
    }
}
```

Then I would like to count each payment on each day.
Using my own method, I could present the data like this:

query:

```
          {
            $group : {
               _id :  { date: "$_id.date",payment_name:"$_id.payment_name" } 
               ,count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
          }
         ,{
            $group : {
               _id :  { date: "$_id.date",payment_name:"$_id.payment_name" }
               ,count:{$sum:"$count"}
            }
          }
         ,{
            $group : {
               _id :  { date: "$_id.date"}
               ,data:{$push:"$$ROOT"}
            }
          }
```

result:

```
 /* 1 */  
     {
        "_id" : {
            "date" : "2018-06-06"
        },
        "data" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : {
                    "date" : "2018-06-06",
                    "payment_name" : "creditcard"
                },
                "count" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : {
                    "date" : "2018-06-06",
                    "payment_name" : "ATM"
                },
                "count" : 1.0
            }
        ]
    }
    /* 2 */  
    {
        "_id" : {
            "date" : "2018-06-07"
        },
        "data" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : {
                    "date" : "2018-06-07",
                    "payment_name" : "creditcard"
                },
                "count_id" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : {
                    "date" : "2018-06-07",
                    "payment_name" : "ATM"
                },
                "count" : 1.0
            }
        ]
    }
```

But the upper result looks a bit messy,
I expected the form to present as below.
How can I use payment's value as key, and count how many times the payment's value had appear.

```
 /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "date" : "2018-06-06"
    },
    "data" :{
            "creditcard" : 1 
            "ATM" : 1
    }

}

/* 2 */
   {
    "_id" : {
        "date" : "2018-06-07"
    },
    "data" :{
            "creditcard" : 1 
            "ATM" : 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Aimee, welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow works best when working with specific code examples, or very targeted questions.

I'd recommend editing your question with the code/query example of what you did in order to get your result, and add any related programming language tags to the question in addition to mongodb, if relevent.

Comment: Point being that "your current output" and "expected output" are good things to have in a question, you really do need to actually show the source data ( as ["minimal"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ) from which such a result can be achieved and then ideally at least what you have done so far to achieve that. Unless other people can "reproduce", then it's unlikely you get a useful answer. We don't sit at your desk. So if we don't have the data then we cannot do it. Also "continuing aggregation pipelines" is not good for your as we can most likely improve on what you already have,

Comment: Hello Ryan, and Neil. Thank you for reminding. I already add the query code above. Please let me know if there's anything not clear enough, thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality you have already done your "aggregation" so there is no actual need to do anything further on the database end. If you have a MongoDB 3.4.4 or later ,then it does actually have the [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator which can be used to reshape the output with a little manipulation in your existing stages:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group":  {
    "date": "$date",
    "order_id": "$order_id",
    "payment_name": "$payment_name"
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "date": "$_id.date",
      "payment_type": "$_id.payment_type"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "date": "$_id.date" },
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id.payment_type",
        "v": "$count"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}
])
```

The "official" documentation says [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) was added with MongoDB 3.6, but in truth it made it's way into the 3.4.4 release and was present in that series after that.

Even if you don't have a version above that, you really don't need it and can simple transform the documents while iterating the cursor results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group":  {
    "date": "$date",
    "order_id": "$order_id",
    "payment_name": "$payment_name"
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "date": "$_id.date",
      "payment_name": "$_id.payment_name"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "date": "$_id.date" },
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id.payment_name",
        "v": "$count"
      }
    }
  }},
  /*
  { "$addFields": {
    "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}
  */
]).map(d =>
  Object.assign(
    d,
    {
      data: d.data.reduce((o,e) => Object.assign(o,{ [e.k]: e.v }),{})
    }
  )
)
```

That's the simple JavaScript transform, and it's not really much different in any language as most have a similar way to transform such different named keys into key/value pairs.

Both forms produce the same output:

```
[
        {
                "_id" : {
                        "date" : "2018-06-06"
                },
                "data" : {
                        "creditcard" : 1,
                        "ATM" : 1
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : {
                        "date" : "2018-06-07"
                },
                "data" : {
                        "ATM" : 1,
                        "creditcard" : 1
                }
        }
]
```